# VB6/IRC PING & PONG Problem

Tags: vb6, irc, ping

I am not able to PONG back the PING to IRC, which sends back a "You must register first" error, here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub wsConnect_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
  Dim strData As String

    wsConnect.GetData strData

    If InStr(strData, "PING") <> 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Success!") 'Check it's receiving it.
        wsConnect.SendData Replace(strData, "PING", "PONG") & vbCrLf
    End If

    Me.txtDataIn.Text = Me.txtDataIn.Text & strData
End Sub
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Again the IRC-protocol defenition in RFC2812 helps: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812

The PING-command from the server looks something like this:

```
PING :3213546231
```

The correct answer on this command is:

```
PONG :3213546231
```

using the same identifier, which was send with the PING.

```
/^PING :(.+)/   -->  respond with "PONG :$1"
```

The error-message points out, that you did not connect the server in a conform way. After establishing the TCP-socket, you have to send the following commands:

```
NICK <yourNickName>
USER <yourUserName> 32 . :<yourRealName>
```

Then you will receive the MOTD. The "PING - PONG" play will begin after this, to make sure your connection is still alive.

**Or you are connecting a server that needs authentication:**

If so, you have to send the command:

```
PASS <yourpassword>
```